# Gaussian random generation with the condition

Tags: java

I do not understand the task.

```
import java.util.*;

public class GaussianRandomNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int k = scanner.nextInt();// for the first seed that is greater or equal to K
        int n = scanner.nextInt();// number of iterations Gaussian
        int m = scanner.nextInt();// Gaussian generated numbers to be less than M
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (random.nextGaussian() <= m & random.nextGaussian() >= k) {
                System.out.println(random.nextGaussian());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the given numbers K, N, and M find the first seed that is greater or equal to K where each of N Gaussian numbers is less than or equal to M.
You have to check all N iterations of Gaussian generated numbers to be less than or equal to M. If that is true, then escape loop and print the seed. If any of the generated numbers is greater than M, then you have to test out the next seed and go to the loop all over again.

Sample Input 1:
0 5 0
Sample Output 1:
38

Why is it 38 if the first seed that is greater or equal to K=0 ?

Comment: You are aware you're creating three random numbers, a different one for each check?

Comment: The given sample input and output is just a (valid) example. When you enter the values `0 5 0` your algorithm should say `38` as the seed to use. So you can verify that your algorithm works fine, but it should obviously work for every input. Btw.: The input for `M` is most likely be supposed to be a `double` since the `nextGaussian()` method is returning a `double` value as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task is asking for a specific "seed" for the given integer inputs. For any pseudo random generator, the "seed" is an internal starting point of the random generator. The random numbers to generate are starting from a value from that "seed". As an example, when you write the following code:

```
Random r = new Random(42);
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    System.out.println(r.nextInt());
}
```

You will always get the following output:

```
-1170105035
234785527
-1360544799
205897768
1325939940
```

*(Warning: Even though the output will always be the same for the same seed, the actual numbers depends on the implementation of the `java.util.Random` class, which might change in future versions. As of writing this answer, the random numbers were generated as these values above with openjdk version "1.8.0_252".)*

Your task is asking for a "seed" which have some defined qualities:

> [...] find the first seed that is greater or equal to `K` [...]

So the argument going into the constructor `new Random(...);` must be greater or equal the value of `K`. So for the input `0 5 0` you might get a different output than for the input `1000 5 0`, since the latter only tries "seed" values greater or equal `1000`. As an example, other "seeds" like 425 shouldn't be tested for the remainder conditions even though they would fit.

> [...] where each of `N` Gaussian numbers [...]

Simple, you generate `N` gaussian numbers and check all of them for the following condition:

> [...] where each of `N` Gaussian numbers **is less than or equal to `M`**.

The `M` is an upper bound for your generated random numbers. The `nextGaussian()` method returns a random number with an average value of `0` (if you continue generating gaussian random numbers), but the return value can be greater or smaller than 0. But in your case all the numbers have to be less or equal `M`.

Your task is now to find the first "seed" which met all these requirements, starting from the "seed" value `K`. Generate `N` numbers and check if they are all at or below `M`. If they aren't, check the next seed.

As an example for the seeds 36, 37 and 38 you will get the following random numbers:

```
Checking seed: 36
1.2723728744482508  <-- fail, not <= K=0
-0.870801422312458
-0.8217339464297395
0.5262022756278059  <-- fail, not <= K=0
0.7755591855768942  <-- fail, not <= K=0

Checking seed: 37
1.7687943677666822   <-- fail, not <= K=0
0.10628211826095219  <-- fail, not <= K=0
1.7204367528361415   <-- fail, not <= K=0
-0.037534100873246996
-0.7556292895100587

Checking seed: 38
-0.5856548327125106
-0.5353713241423471
-0.6629651900370352
-0.06602762115722295
-0.5573859875224596
```

As you see, the seed `38` is the first which met the conditions, for **this specific input**. If you change the input condition you might get a different seed value. In fact, when you increase the limit `N` for the count of random numbers to generate from `5` to `10` you will not met the conditions anymore:

```
Checking with random number generator seed: 36
1.2723728744482508    <-- fail, not <= K=0
-0.870801422312458
-0.8217339464297395
0.5262022756278059    <-- fail, not <= K=0
0.7755591855768942    <-- fail, not <= K=0
0.1050333460099397    <-- fail, not <= K=0
-1.2195748465234115
-0.5682199782926214
-0.6364150668125728
1.0752773722411306    <-- fail, not <= K=0

Checking with random number generator seed: 37
1.7687943677666822     <-- fail, not <= K=0
0.10628211826095219    <-- fail, not <= K=0
1.7204367528361415     <-- fail, not <= K=0
-0.037534100873246996
-0.7556292895100587
-0.9951161662703086
1.052027068066767      <-- fail, not <= K=0
-0.6497562324361997
-0.47969604178646064
1.3195412359422278     <-- fail, not <= K=0

Checking with random number generator seed: 38
-0.5856548327125106
-0.5353713241423471
-0.6629651900370352
-0.06602762115722295
-0.5573859875224596
0.5414339383037863     <-- fail, not <= K=0
-1.9350302385094755
1.7250885444038893     <-- fail, not <= K=0
-1.2161902995946092
-0.16606956096867706
```

Notice, how the first five numbers in each run are the same even after rerun your code (because of the same seed for the random number generator). But also notice that you generated two numbers for the seed `38` which are now greater than `K=0`. So the output `38` is correct for the input `0 5 0`, but it is not correct for the input `0 10 0`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the description of the problem is pretty clear.

1. You have to check all N iterations of Gaussian generated numbers to be less than or equal to M.
2. If that is true, then escape loop and print the seed.
3. If any of the generated numbers is greater than M, then you have to test out the next seed and go to the loop all over again.

So I literally followed the instructions and this is what I've got.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        double m = sc.nextDouble();

        // your initial seed starts with k
        Random random = new Random(k);

        // variable to check if all N iterations are valid (<=M)
        int check = 0;

        // you need an outer loop because like in #3, 
        // if there is an invalid number you have to iterate N times again
        while (true) {

            // this is the N iterations you need
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

                // at each iteration, you generate a Gaussian number
                double randomNumber = random.nextGaussian();

                // again #3: if the generated number is greater than M, move on the the next seed
                if (randomNumber > m) {
                    random.setSeed(++k);    //moving on to the next seed
                    check = 0;  // don't forget to initialize the check variable too
                    break;
                }
                check++;
            }
            // if all N iterations have passed, that's your answer
            if (check == n) {
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand correctly what you're trying to do, but you generate three different random numbers each iteration, so you check the upper and lower limits against different numbers and then output yet another one.

This seems to make more sense to me:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    double randomNumber = random.nextGaussian();
    // check the generated number against the limits
    if (randomNumber <= m & randomNumber >= k) {
        // output it if within limits
        System.out.println(randomNumber);
    }
}
```

Note: a "seed" is something different, it's a starting point for the random number generation, not the generated number itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
 import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
        int k = scanner.nextInt();
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        double m = scanner.nextDouble();

        for (int i = k; ; i++) {
            Random random = new Random(i);
            int j = 0;
            for (; j < n; j++) {

                if (random.nextGaussian() > m) {
                    break;

                }

            }

            if (j == n) {
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: It wouldnt hurt give some details about your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // write your code here
        final long k = scanner.nextLong();
        final long n = scanner.nextLong();
        final double m = scanner.nextDouble();
        long seed = k;
        Random rand = new Random(seed);
        while (Stream.generate(rand::nextGaussian).limit(n).anyMatch(i -> i > m)) {
           rand.setSeed(++seed);
        }
        System.out.println(seed);
    }
}
```